# Run subquery on each result of query in MS Access

Tags: sql, ms-access-2016

I am currently using this SQL in a PHP app and need to convert to MS Access.

I need to run the second query against each result from the first to end up with a count of riders in each race the rider in the first race ran. (motorcycle racing events)

Quite simple with PHP (I can provide the complete code for that if needed)

Not real sure how to even begin with Access. (both query's work fine in Access, just not able to join them how I need to)

Query 1:

```
SELECT schedule2.Date, riders.ridername, results.finish, results.points, classes.class, seasons.season
FROM schedule2 RIGHT JOIN (classes RIGHT JOIN ((riders RIGHT JOIN results ON riders.id = results.rider_id) LEFT JOIN seasons ON results.season_id = seasons.id) ON classes.id = results.class_id) ON schedule2.id = results.schedule_id
GROUP BY schedule2.Date, riders.ridername, results.finish, results.points, classes.class, seasons.season, schedule2.id, results.class_id, riders.id
HAVING (((riders.id)=[:id]))
ORDER BY schedule2.Date;
```

Query 2:

```
SELECT DISTINCT Count(results.rider_id) AS CountOfrider_id
FROM seasons RIGHT JOIN (results LEFT JOIN schedule2 ON results.schedule_id = schedule2.id) ON seasons.id = schedule2.season_id
GROUP BY schedule2.id, results.class_id
HAVING (((schedule2.id)=[:scheduleId]) AND ((results.class_id)=[:classId]));
```

The current PHP app produces this result set: (the rider id is picked with a form)

[image]

Original PHP (for reference)

```
            $getRiderInfo = $dbh->prepare('
                    SELECT riders.ridername, 
                          schedule2.date, 
                          schedule2.id AS scheduleId, 
                          results.class_id AS classId, 
                          results.finish, 
                          results.points, 
                          classes.class, 
                          seasons.season, 
                          riders.id 
                    FROM schedule2 
                    RIGHT JOIN (classes 
                                RIGHT JOIN ((riders 
                                             RIGHT JOIN results 
                                             ON riders.id = results.rider_id) 
                    LEFT JOIN seasons 
                      ON results.season_id = seasons.id) 
                      ON classes.id = results.class_id) 
                      ON schedule2.id = results.schedule_id
                    GROUP BY riders.ridername, 
                             schedule2.date, 
                             classes.class, 
                             seasons.season
                    HAVING (((riders.id)=:id))
                    ORDER BY schedule2.date ASC;
            ');
            $getRiderInfo->bindValue('id', $racer_id);
            if ($getRiderInfo->execute()) {
                while ($iRows = $getRiderInfo->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
                    $getCounts = $dbh->prepare('
                            SELECT DISTINCT COUNT(results.rider_id) AS CountOfrider_id,
                                   schedule2.id,
                                   results.class_id
                            FROM seasons
                            RIGHT JOIN(results
                            LEFT JOIN schedule2
                            ON results.schedule_id = schedule2.id) 
                            ON seasons.id = schedule2.season_id
                            GROUP BY schedule2.id , 
                                     results.class_id
                            HAVING (((schedule2.id) = :scheduleId)
                            AND ((results.class_id) = :classId));
                    ');
                    $getCounts->bindValue('scheduleId', $iRows['scheduleId']);
                    $getCounts->bindValue('classId', $iRows['classId']);
                    if ($getCounts->execute()) {
                        while ($iRows1 = $getCounts->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
                            $iCount = $iRows1['CountOfrider_id'];
                        }
                    }
                    $iDate = date_create($iRows['date']);
                    echo '<tr><td>' . $iRows['ridername'] . '</td>';
                    echo '<td>' . date_format($iDate, 'm/d/Y') . '</td>';
                    echo '<td>' . $iRows['finish'] . '</td>';
                    echo '<td>' . $iRows['points'] . '</td>';
                    echo '<td>' . $iRows['class'] . '</td>';
                    echo '<td>' . $iRows['season'] . '</td>';
                    echo '<td>' . $iCount . '</td></tr>';
                }
            }
```

Comment: RIGHT JOIN's combined with LEFT JOIN's?!?

Comment: *"RIGHT JOIN's combined with LEFT JOIN's?!? "* topicstarter i understand @jarlh comment it looks wierd i assume you needed to simulate MySQL missing support for "FULL JOIN" with that?   ... topicstarter because this question is unclear see [Why should I provide a Minimal Reproducible Example for a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: @jarth, yeah I know it looks strange and I honestly don't recall why I wrote it that way (4 yr old code), but I recall it's what I had to do in order to make it work.

Comment: *"I honestly don't recall why I wrote it that way (4 yr old code), but I recall it's what I had to do in order to make it work"* @indymx see mine link about providing example data and expected results as i am pretty sure this query can be rewritten better as your current query looks like a unneeded *"explode (LEFT/RIGHT JOINs) / implode (GROUP BY/HAVING) method"* to get your results..

Comment: @RaymondNijland I will definitely do that tonight after work.

Comment: Sample data, desired results, and a clear explanation of the logic would help.

Answer (score 0):

I found a better way around this problem. Actually I was kind of over thinking things.

This dataset is never going to change, so, that second query isn't really needed, just ran it once to create a table with the total count I'm looking for for column 6 and added another join to the first query. (too many joins already to keep track of.)

It works for my purpose.